# Running static with `%matplotlib notebook`

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter

How can I tell matplotlib/jupyter to make a non-interactive plot using `%matplotlib notebook`?

Currently, I'm using `%matplotlib notebook` for some things, but would prefer to use regular `%matplotlib inline` elsewhere. Is there a way to specify non-interactive plots?